# violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> First of all, it's not a duplicate! I already saw some related questions about it and I tried to do what they said in those answers and didn't work..

Here is an image of my database structure 
[image: entity relationship diagram]

As you can see, everything is all right, the relations were established correctly **BUT** when I try to add an event appears this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tvfootball`.`all_streams`, CONSTRAINT `fk_channels` FOREIGN KEY (`channel_id`) REFERENCES `channels` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\admin\addStream.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\admin\addStream.php(16): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\admin\addStream.php on line 16

and if I try to insert an channel, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tvfootball`.`all_streams`, CONSTRAINT `fk_events` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\admin\addStream.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\admin\addStream.php(31): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\admin\addStream.php on line 31

The thing is... It inserts data to **streams** table, BUT doesn't insert anything in **all_streams**

**Here is my SQL**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `all_streams`;
CREATE TABLE `all_streams` (
  `event_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `stream_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `fk_streams` (`stream_id`),
  KEY `fk_events` (`event_id`),
  KEY `fk_channels` (`channel_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_channels` FOREIGN KEY (`channel_id`) REFERENCES `channels` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_streams` FOREIGN KEY (`stream_id`) REFERENCES `streams` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Here is my PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['addStreamsEvents'])){
extract($_POST);
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO streams (link) VALUES (?)");
$statement->bindParam(1,$stream);
$statement->execute();

$id=$db->lastInsertId();

$statement_join = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_streams (event_id,stream_id)VALUES (?,?)");
$statement_join->bindParam(1,$event);
$statement_join->bindParam(2,$id);
$statement_join->execute();
}

if(isset($_POST['addStreamsChannels'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO streams (link) VALUES (?)");
    $statement->bindParam(1,$stream);
    $statement->execute();

    $id=$db->lastInsertId();

    $statement_join = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_streams (channel_id, stream_id) VALUES (?,?)");
    $statement_join->bindParam(1,$event);
    $statement_join->bindParam(2,$id);
    $statement_join->execute();
}
```

Does someone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**BTW:**

I already tried it: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` and didn't work..

Comment: Are you aware that you must insert the `event`, the `channel` *and* the `stream` before you can insert a record into `all_streams`?

Comment: Yes, of course, I already have data inserted in `event` and `channels`

Comment: `INSERT INTO all_streams (channel_id, stream_id) VALUES (?,?)` is invalid with your constraints. The constraints enforce that `stream_id`, `event_id` and `channel_id` are non-null and reference a corresponding record.

Comment: In other words, *every* insert into `all_streams` *must* provide non-null values for all *three* FK columns.

Comment: Ohhh, but my ideia is: when I insert the **channel_id**, the **event_id** should be null and vice-versa..

Comment: How can I apply my ideia?

Comment: But, @JimmyB, If I insert an event_id and the channel_id is null, it doesn't give me any error..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. In fact, FK columns *can* be null, depending on your settings.

Comment: Are you sure the values you are inserting are valid IDs?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure !

Comment: Do you have `0` as ID in `streams`?

Comment: no, I don't, why?

Comment: Wait, I test it in navicat, and Its everything okay, I can add channel_id and leave the evnt_id in blank and vice-versa... I just get the error now IN php

Comment: Sorry, I have no further clues. You're narrowing down the problem some more now?

Comment: No the problem now is just in PHP when i try to insert some data in

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you have a default value of zero set on a foreign key constrained column, but as [you said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/68105795), the value of zero doesn't exist as a primary key, so your insert fails because you don't specify it in the query.

```
`event_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`stream_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
```

If you're going to keep using this default, then you must explicitly insert `NULL` or a valid id.

Here's [a working example](https://github.com/scratchers/so-streams-events-channels/commit/b550b6c03cf29d88e1a3e963c731156d7ce7854b) that changes this:

```sql
INSERT INTO all_streams (event_id,stream_id) VALUES (?,?)
```

into this:

```sql
INSERT INTO all_streams (event_id,stream_id,channel_id) VALUES (?,?, NULL)
```

However, I think the best thing would be to remove those default values, because it doesn't make sense to me, [which works also](https://github.com/scratchers/so-streams-events-channels/commit/b550b6c03cf29d88e1a3e963c731156d7ce7854b).

It's unclear without seeing your form, but another problem you might not have noticed is that you're using the same input value named `event` for `event_id` and `channel_id`

```
$statement_join = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_streams (event_id,stream_id)VALUES (?,?)");
$statement_join->bindParam(1,$event);
...
$statement_join = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_streams (channel_id, stream_id) VALUES (?,?)");
$statement_join->bindParam(1,$event);
```

Here's [the working example](https://github.com/scratchers/so-streams-events-channels) reproduced as best I could filling in the missing values for your tables and form.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="addStreamsEvents"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="addStreamsChannels"/>

    <label for="stream">Stream</label>
    <input type="text" name="stream"/>

    <label for="event">Event or Channel ID</label>
    <input type="number" name="event" value="1"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php

// returns an instance of PDO
// https://github.com/jpuck/qdbp
$db = require __DIR__.'/streams_Dtm905_A.pdo.php';

if(isset($_POST['addStreamsEvents'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO streams (link) VALUES (?)");
    $statement->bindParam(1,$stream);
    $statement->execute();

    $id=$db->lastInsertId();

    $statement_join = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_streams (event_id,stream_id) VALUES (?,?)");
    $statement_join->bindParam(1,$event);
    $statement_join->bindParam(2,$id);
    $statement_join->execute();
}

if(isset($_POST['addStreamsChannels'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO streams (link) VALUES (?)");
    $statement->bindParam(1,$stream);
    $statement->execute();

    $id=$db->lastInsertId();

    $statement_join = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO all_streams (channel_id, stream_id) VALUES (?,?)");
    $statement_join->bindParam(1,$event);
    $statement_join->bindParam(2,$id);
    $statement_join->execute();
}
```

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `all_streams`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `streams`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `events`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `channels`;

CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(11)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `something` varchar(11)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `streams` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `link` varchar(11)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `all_streams` (
  `event_id` int(11),
  `stream_id` int(11),
  `channel_id` int(11),
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY `fk_streams` (`stream_id`),
  KEY `fk_events` (`event_id`),
  KEY `fk_channels` (`channel_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_channels` FOREIGN KEY (`channel_id`) REFERENCES `channels` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_streams` FOREIGN KEY (`stream_id`) REFERENCES `streams` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- seed data
INSERT INTO `channels` (`name`)      VALUES ('channel 1');
INSERT INTO `events`   (`something`) VALUES ('event   1');
```

Answer (score 0):

In a few words, you have references on non-existing records (null values).

For instance, you want to add your foreign keys to the and you have already had a record in table `all streams` with `event_id`=14, `stream_id`=2, `channel_id`=91 (or vice versa have already had constraints but want to add a record) but in the table `events` there is no record with `id`=14 or/and there is no record in the `stream` table with `id`=2 or/and there is no record in the `channel` table with `id`=91.

Also, you are not allowed to set default values for foreign keys!